# JQM - Get checkbox value to put in db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to retrieve the state of a checkbox and insert its value into a mysql database.

what is the best way to do this?

i have a submit button and i was hoping i could pass the state to another page(Dialog) and insert the values there like i have been doing with post with php variable.

A little kick in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
    <label for="checker">a checkbox:</label>
<select name="checker" id="checker" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">No</option>
    <option value="on">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve it with PHP or jQuery?

Comment: retrieving it with php isnt an option is it? well if the page has already been executed, then the state of the checkbox gets changed, i would like to pass the state to another page and retrieve the value there to process the data. im guessing some sort of ajax call is my option although my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Whether it was an option or not is obvious to you. However not to us.   We can't read mind. These details help to make your question clearer and easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checbox works like other input, U just need to use the same name ex:"checkvalue[]" and they will collect all the checkbox value.